# BOW with more 2-classes SVMs of one multiclass SVM

Tags: opencv, svm

Because the OpenCV's forum has a problem, I want to post the question here too.

In the example of BOW from OpenCV, there is trained a 2-classes SVM classifier for each class. So why isn't use a multi-class SVM instead? If I do like this, then, supposing I have X classes, I have to load X SVMs and predict X times for an image.

Because the code is very large and uses a large dataset, it takes too long for doing my research.

---

[ I have managed to start training a first SVM classifier with the OpenCV's BOW example, but it says:

> 143 positive training samples; 2356 negative training samples

I am wondering if this will not be a bad classifier... but maybe `train_auto` will find the needed parameters so it will not be bad. What do you think? ]